# Is it possible to pass a python string by reference through ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm sorry, but I generally have a hard time reading the current ctypes docs...

If I have a C function that takes a `const char *` pointer, and I *know* it will neither modify the passed in string, nor keep a reference to it beyond the function call, it really makes sense to pass in a pointer directly to the bytes of a python string.

Can ctypes can do this or is it just plain unsupported? Do I really have to `create_string_buffer` and copy my string into it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Assigning a new value to instances of the pointer types c_char_p, c_wchar_p, and c_void_p changes the memory location they point to, not the contents of the memory block (of course not, because Python strings are immutable):
>
> ```
> >>> s = "Hello, World"
> >>> c_s = c_char_p(s)
> >>> print c_s
> c_char_p('Hello, World')
> >>> c_s.value = "Hi, there"
> >>> print c_s
> c_char_p('Hi, there')
> >>> print s                 # first string is unchanged
> Hello, World
> >>>
> ```
>
> You should be careful, however, not to
> pass them to functions expecting
> pointers to mutable memory. If you
> need mutable memory blocks, ctypes has
> a create_string_buffer function which
> creates these in various ways. The
> current memory block contents can be
> accessed (or changed) with the raw
> property, if you want to access it as
> NUL terminated string, use the string
> property:

Says the ctypes tutorial. What I gather from this is that only if the function would work with a `const char*`, would passing in the python string be valid. Keep in mind, it won't have a null termination.

I'd suggest using `create_string_buffer` anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, you are entirely correct. I even vaguely remember reading this before. I despise the ctypes docs for putting key information in the tutorials.

Comment: I hear you on that. Python documents are great, except when you need to look something up. Then you'll need to read everything related to what you want to do.

I can't stress enough though, the string you pas in will not be null terminated. So do not use any std::string or string.h functions on them. )

Comment: a Python string passed to ctypes *will* be nul-terminated.  It is valid to pass a Python string to a function that takes the c_char_p type.

Comment: it'll only be null terminated is you pass it through create_string_buffer. python strings have no null terminator.

Comment: Look closely at all the examples in the `ctypes` tutorial.  The examples call `printf`, `strchr`, etc. with Python strings and they *will* be nul-terminated.  `create_string_buffer` is only needed for *mutable* strings.

Comment: @bryanegr is referencing specifically [ctypes section 15.17.1.4](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types).

Answer (score 6):

The type [ctypes.c_char_p](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes.c_char_p) represents a nul-terminated string.  If a function takes a const char* you can pass a Python string to it and it will receive a nul-terminated version.

A Windows example DLL:

```
#include <string.h>

__declspec(dllexport) char* func(char* a,size_t len,const char* b)
{
    if(strlen(b) * 2 >= len)
        return NULL;
    strcpy_s(a,len,b);
    strcat_s(a,len,b);
    return a;
}
```

Python:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> x=CDLL('x')
>>> x.func.restype=c_char_p
>>> x.func.argtypes=[c_char_p,c_int,c_char_p]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(10)
>>> x.func(s,len(s),'abcd')
'abcdabcd'
>>>
```

Comment: Python docs say ... "None, integers, longs, byte strings and unicode strings are the only native Python objects that can directly be used as parameters in these function calls. ... byte strings and unicode strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that contains their data (char * or wchar_t *)." ... in the section on [Calling Functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions), right before [Fundamental Data Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)

Comment: Python documentation for the Python C API function [PyString_AsString](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/string.html?highlight=pystring#c.PyString_AsString): *Return a NUL-terminated representation of the contents of string. The pointer refers to the internal buffer of string, not a copy*.  The internal string buffers are nul-terminated.