# passing string to c dll expecting const unsigned char* in python

Tags: python, c

I feel sorry, but I generally have a hard time reading the ctypes docs...

If I have a C function that takes a const unsigned char* pointer, and I know it will neither modify the passed in string, nor keep a reference to it beyond the function call, it really makes sense to pass in a pointer directly to the bytes of a python string.

I followed 2 approach

```
approach1:

cdll.func.restype=c_int
cdll.func.argtypes[c_int,c_int,c_int,c_char_p,c_int,c_char_p,c_int]
cdll.func(0,1,0,'11011101001111111000110011111',60,'0',80)

cdll function


 int func(inta,int b,int c, const unsigned char* cptr1 ,int ,const unsigned char* cptr2,int d){
       // do some string operation
       return 0;
    }

approach2:

v ='11011101001111111000110011111'
j = '0'
cdll.func(0,1,0,v,60,j,80)

  int func(inta,int b,int c, const unsigned char* cptr1 ,int ,const unsigned char* cptr2,int d){
       // do some string operation
       return 0;
    }
```

[I done some research here link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576925/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-python-string-by-reference-through-ctypes)

But it doesn't help , is it really to do typecast kind of thing in python? but if i do this , it does work. Thanks in advance

Comment: But isn't there a mismatch in how you call the function from python, in regards to how the function actually is defined? You say in your Python code that the function takes three integers, a string, another integer, another string and then a last integer, but the function is defined to only take a single string argument. That will of course not work as expected, since the function will receive the first integer and use it as a string pointer.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg I have playing around with code, please have a look at the problem statement now.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer ? It's also a suggested solution in the question you linked.

Comment: @ sebastine Thanks alot, could you please direct me which function i have to use for this? create_string_buffer or  ctypes.byref(obj[, offset]), It is highly appreciated, if there is any code example or links to solve this

Comment: Just search trough the ctypes documenation and you'll find: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference

Comment: v= "0x200000e000600"
        c_s = c_char_p(v)
        j="0"
        d_s = c_char_p(j)
        cdll.func(0,6,0,c_s.value,50,d_s.value,90) But still doesn't work, it there any other way? @ sebastin, is this is the right approach?

Comment: Could you post any error message you are getting, the version of python you are using and the OS you are using?

Comment: @ Duke error : TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance Os:win 7 python version : 3.4

Comment: Well then you have to use `bytes` instances instead of `str`.  `str` is a unicode object in Python 3.  Nothing C ”understands”.  So you either have to pass `bytes` objects or encode the `str` objects as `bytes`.

Comment: @ BlackJack , How do i pass byte instance could you please explain?

Comment: See the answer from @sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

The below is what I would have concluded from the ctypes documenation:

```
v = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'11011101001111111000110011111')
j = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'0')
cdll.func(0,1,0,v,60,j,80)
```

The `ctypes` functions `create_string_buffer` and `create_unicode_buffer` were not renamed / changed in Python 3. So `create_string_buffer` does really create a buffer of bytes.

An attempt to pass u_chars:

```
def uchar_array(s):
    # construct array type of proper length including
    # zero-termination
    cls = ctypes.c_ubyte * (len(s)+1)

    # initialize with the provided bytes
    instance = cls(*list(s))

    # terminate with a zero
    instance[len(s)] = 0
    return instance

v = uchar_array(b'11011101001111111000110011111')
j = uchar_array(b'0')
cdll.func(0,1,0,v,60,j,80)
```

Comment: Thanks I got that const unsigned char* pointer is expecting packed unsigned charcaters from python, is it possible to send as packed bytes in python.

Comment: @Sandy What are _packed bytes_?  A `bytes` object contains a sequence of bytes just like a `char` array or ”string” in C.