# How to generate DLL from matlab R14 and call by python 3.5

Tags: python, matlab, dll

I have some matlab code (split over 4 files `test.m, a.m, b.m, c.m`) from which I'd like to generate DLL file to be called by external application. The main function `test(x, y, z)` in `test.m` contains three inputs of type string without any output argument - it writes some data into a file.

I'm generating the from matlab DLL with:

```
mcc -B csharedlib:testLib test.m a.m b.m c.m
```

I'm receiving some files and DLL.

Now I'm calling this DLL by following python code:

```
from ctypes import *

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("testLib.dll")
mydll.test("string1", "string2", "string3")
```

On the 2nd line I'm getting following error: `"OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"`

Any idea where there is a problem?

P.S. don't ask why I'm using this version of Matlab (I'd prefer to use a newer one).

Comment: Check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/408981-how-can-i-compile-with-matlab-a-dll-that-can-be-used-in-python-code) post. And read MATLAB [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/matlab-compiler-generated-interface-functions.html). Executing  `mydll.testLibInitialize()` and `mydll.testLibTerminate()` works fine, but passing strings ??? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576925/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-python-string-by-reference-through-ctypes) post.

Comment: I am using newer MATLAB version, use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for checking the DLL interface functions. Make sure you are not mixing x86 and x64 architectures...